# error in SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near

Tags: mysql, joomla, joomla3.0, mysql-error-1064

I am stuck in a problem. I have found error  `1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') AND block = 0 ORDER BY name' at line 1 SQL=SELECT id AS value, name AS text FROM crna_users WHERE id NOT IN ( ) AND block = 0 ORDER BY name"` when i click on the new menu button in administrator.

Please help to sought it out.

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 3.4.10.1deb1
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: Oct 13, 2014 at 01:29 PM
-- Server version: 5.5.38
-- PHP Version: 5.5.17-2+deb.sury.org~precise+1

SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `joomlaolddatabase`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `crna_users`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `crna_users` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `username` varchar(150) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `password` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `usertype` varchar(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `block` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `sendEmail` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
 `gid` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 `registerDate` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 `lastvisitDate` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 `activation` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `params` text NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `usertype` (`usertype`),
 KEY `idx_name` (`name`),
 KEY `gid_block` (`gid`,`block`),
 KEY `username` (`username`),
 KEY `email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3076 ;
```

Comment: The code part that you have shared does not contain the `select` part that prompt the error.

Comment: Can you add the sql statement that is running?

Comment: The error is in the IN because is empty, post the code where you run the `SELECT` part

Answer (score 0):

I too encountered this problem while trying to import a database to MySql. I had exported a version of a database from my local machine and i wanted to import it to the server where my website is hosted. problem was that there was a mismatch between the versions of the two systems. 
I managed to get around the problem by using the compatibility option(both while exporting and while importing). i used "MYSQL323".
This fixed my problem. I think this is a good solution for those who have the possibility to make a fresh exported version of the database.